# Как в Bitrix хранятся поля товаров из 1С?

Tags: битрикс, 1с, интернет-магазин, интеграция

Как происходит интеграция товаров в Битрикс из 1С? Где и как хранятся 1С-ные коды для привязки? Или там это происходит как-то по другому?

В UMI, к примеру, есть таблица соответствия товар магазина->товар из 1С.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Интеграция 1С-Битрикс и 1С с помощью модуля обмена осуществляется с помощью xml-файлов формата CommerceML. Из 1С на сайт выгружается несколько файлов. Примерное содержание:

- import.xml - содержащий описание структуры каталога на сайте
- rests.xml - информация о складах
- prices.xml - информация о ценах и их типах
- offers.xml - информация о предложениях/товарах/ со свойствами

Связь и идентификация проходит по `GUID` элемента в 1С и `Внешнего кода` или `XML_ID` на сайте. Для свойств и их значение используется соответственно `GUID` свойства и `GUID` значения свойства, которые на сайте видны как `XML_ID` в таблице свойств инфоблока. Построение xml-файлов модулями обмена основано на создании файлов описывающих структуры, где ключевым/основным элементам и их потомках прописываются `GUID`, а затем уже в общем списке товаров вместо значений подставляются именно `GUID`ы. Обработка на сайте/обновление/считывание файла загруженного 1Ской идет по этим самым `GUID`ам.

Все необходимые 1Сные коды (GUID) присвоенные при выгрузке на сайт вы можеме просмотреть в xml-файлах. Или же в соответствующих таблицах в 1С.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый и информативный ответ. Он мне очень помог.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения.